# Python tkinter simpledialog

Tags: python, tkinter, nameerror, simpledialog

I have a Python script which generates a GUI window with tkinter library. I'd like to make some of it's buttons display a prompt - small window to ask the user for some number (something like in JavaScript). I tried the following command:

```
x = tkinter.simpledialog.askstring
```

But it returns an error:

```
NameError: name 'tkinter' is not defined
```

and no prompt is generated, although I have imported the library in the script's beginning:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import simpledialog
```

Other elements (buttons, labels etc.) in the main window work correctly. Please help.

Comment: Remove the prefix `tkinter.`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`askstring`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#tkinter.simpledialog.askstring) is part of `tkinter.simpledialog` so you might import it like so

```
from tkinter.simpledialog import askstring
```

usage example

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.simpledialog import askstring
root = tk.Tk()
x = askstring("Title", "Prompt")
print(x)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why does your code pop up in two windows instead of only one? One window has the title "Title" while the other one has the title "tk". How can I remove the second window?